# Why does Python ignore elif?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why python ignore elife in my code? It's only check if YouTube(link) and if it is False, python run else section and completely ignore elife section.
Does anyone know why this happens & how can I fix this ? I really appreciate.

Here is my code :

```
from time import sleep
from pytube.contrib.playlist import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube
import pytube.request
    
while True:
    try:
        link = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIr8YTyhDSA2b5d0vlbM1gdAwzWYpeNpA'
        if YouTube(link):
            print(f'\n I found " {YouTube(link).title} " for you :)')
            v = input(" press 'No' or 'N' if it's not what you are looking for \ anything else to continue ")
            if v not in ('N', 'n' , 'no' , 'No'):
                yt=YouTube(link)
                break
        elif Playlist(link):
            print(f'\n I found " {Playlist(link).title} " for you :)')
            v = input(" press 'No' or 'N' if it's not what you are looking for \ anything else to continue ")
            if v not in ('N', 'n' , 'no' , 'No'):
                yt=Playlist(link)
                break
        else:
            print("link is not valid")
    except pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError as link_error:
            print(' {} link error, try again {}'.format(3*"\N{Cross Mark}",3*"\N{Cross Mark}"))
```

If I change Youtube(link) with Playlist(link) its work fine but then
if I fill the link as one single video url(not playlist url) I will have same problem again & the elife section will be ignore again :/

Comment: Maybe `Playlist(link)` is false.

Comment: that would mean `Playlist(link)` is false too

Comment: after `link = ...`, do `print(bool(YouTube(link)), bool(Playlist(link)))` and you'll see

Comment: Maybe both are true, and so whichever one you put first is always the one that'll happen?

Comment: `YouTube(link)` is always true?

Comment: if/elif runs until it finds the first true thing, then stops. If `YouTube(link)` is `True`, the following `elif` and `else` will not run. You could write a simpler script that replaces the youtube and playlist calls with their result - `if True:` for example. That would make this much easier to test.

Comment: The link I enterd is a youtube playlist so Youtube(link) is False & Playlist(link) is True (I test then both on seperate script than this one that I shared)

Comment: I did the print(bool(YouTube(link)), bool(Playlist(link))) after the Link line & suprisley havent get the output , its like print(bool(YouTube(link)), bool(Playlist(link))) ignored too :/

Comment: Please post the script where you print the boolean values. It should just be the imports, the link and two lines that print. When I ran this https://pastebin.com/kvtrERFK, I got a regex error... not sure why. When you run it, what do you get?

Comment: @tdelaney damn, I just notice this whole time I was getting regex error, now I have another problem lol , I think I should delete the code and rewrite it again with better syntax , thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

`YouTube` is a class constructor, so calling it will always evaluate to "true" (i.e. it's never going to return a falsey value like `None` or `False`).  `YouTube(url)` is therefore not an effective way of checking if the url is valid, and your `if/elif` is just always going to execute that first `if` block.

Based on a very quick skim of the docs, I think you might want something like:

```
from pytube.exceptions import RegexMatchError, VideoUnavailable

def is_valid_youtube_link(url: str) -> bool:
    try:
        YouTube(url).check_availability()
        return True
    except (RegexMatchError, VideoUnavailable):
        return False
```

or maybe:

```
from pytube.exceptions import RegexMatchError, VideoUnavailable
from typing import Optional

def get_youtube_if_available(url: str) -> Optional[YouTube]:
    try:
        yt = YouTube(url)
        yt.check_availability()
        return yt
    except (RegexMatchError, VideoUnavailable):
        return None
```

You'll want to review the `pytube` documentation for more on how to use the `YouTube` and `Playlist` objects: https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#youtube-object

Comment: Thank you for your response and useful info, but I should say that Youtube won’t always return True, You can enter the wrong URL in my code, and you will see the else section will run

Comment: When I run your code, the `YouTube` constructor raises an exception (it looks like it's because the URL doesn't match the regex for a YouTube video), so neither the `if` nor `elif` is executed.  The approach I outlined above with catching the exception in a helper function should help with that problem as well.

Comment: yeah I got it, thanks man

Comment: Well, what should I do bout Playlist? It doesn't have  check_availability() methods

Comment: I dunno, you'd have to look more closely into the doc to see how you figure out if a playlist is valid.  Maybe you want to check its `length`?  Whether a playlist is "valid" might depend more on what you want to do with it in the rest of your script.

Comment: I already write my script it's a YouTube downloader you can see it here pastebin.com/4iS3S21D, I just want to add playlist option, and you're right I should check the docs deeper, thanks again